# Completion menu closes after typing more characters in substring matches

Tags: autocompletion, ins-completion

Let's assume you have the following completefunc defintion:

```
vim9script

const py_keywords = [
    { 'word': 'pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.argsort'},
    { 'word': 'pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.astype'}
    ]

def PyComplete(findstart: number, base: string): any
    if findstart
        # locate the start of the word
        var line = getline('.')
        var start = col('.') - 1
        while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '[0-9A-Za-z_.]'
            start -= 1
        endwhile
        return start
    else
        var pattern = '.*' .. base .. '.*'
        var matches = copy(py_keywords)->filter((i, x) => x.word =~ pattern)
        for m in matches
            complete_add(m)
        endfor
        return []
    endif
enddef

set completefunc=PyComplete
```

Notice that instead of the commonly used `'^' .. base` pattern matching, this is filtering based on substrings `'.*' .. base .. '.*'`. The previous function works well when you start from very beginning of the matches (in this example, with the letter `p`) and keep typing in order to reduce the number of suggestions. However, the menu immediately closes when you start from any other substring (e.g. `arg`). This behavior can be seen in the following screencast:

[image]

Is there some way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I can't really find a good way to do this; the completion is "prefix based". Hooking in to `CompleteDonePre` or `TextChangedP` to show the menu again when desired is probably the best bet, but I can't really get that to work right now either.

Comment: Exactly. I also had the impression that completion is prefix based regardless of the pattern match used in either iteration. If there is not a simple way to do this, maybe this could be a good feature request.